# How to get arraypoints from kml file in android

Tags: android, google-maps, polygon, kml

I have kml file and I display it in my map with `KmlLayer` class. (it is a polygon shape that dispaly in the map)
Now I need to check if the user locaion is in the polygon or not.
how can i get the coordinates of the polygon and check if the user in it or not?

this is the mapActivity

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, LocationListener {

private GoogleMap mMap;
private  LocationManager manager;
private double lat, lng;
private KmlLayer layer;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    manager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    String provider = LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER;

    try {
        manager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 1000, 100, this);
    }catch (SecurityException e){

    }
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

}


@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    // Add a marker in user location

    mMap.clear();
    try {
        layer = new KmlLayer(mMap, R.raw.polygon_layer, this);
        layer.addLayerToMap();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    lat = location.getLatitude();
    lng = location.getLongitude();
    LatLng userLocation = new LatLng(lat , lng );
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(userLocation).title("you are here"));
    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(userLocation, 15));
/////do somethig thith the results.../////
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

  }
}
```

this is the kml file in xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:gx="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2" xmlns:kml="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
<Document>
    <name>Allowed area.kml</name>
    <Style id="s_ylw-pushpin_hl">
        <IconStyle>
            <scale>1.3</scale>
            <Icon>
                <href>http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/pushpin/ylw-pushpin.png</href>
            </Icon>
            <hotSpot x="20" y="2" xunits="pixels" yunits="pixels"/>
        </IconStyle>
    </Style>
    <StyleMap id="m_ylw-pushpin">
        <Pair>
            <key>normal</key>
            <styleUrl>#s_ylw-pushpin</styleUrl>
        </Pair>
        <Pair>
            <key>highlight</key>
            <styleUrl>#s_ylw-pushpin_hl</styleUrl>
        </Pair>
    </StyleMap>
    <Style id="s_ylw-pushpin">
        <IconStyle>
            <scale>1.1</scale>
            <Icon>
                <href>http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/pushpin/ylw-pushpin.png</href>
            </Icon>
            <hotSpot x="20" y="2" xunits="pixels" yunits="pixels"/>
        </IconStyle>
    </Style>
    <Placemark>
        <name>Allowed area</name>
        <styleUrl>#m_ylw-pushpin</styleUrl>
        <Polygon>
            <tessellate>1</tessellate>
            <outerBoundaryIs>
                <LinearRing>
                    <coordinates>
                        34.79991805485883,32.070779943443,0 34.799829164854,32.07080649750882,0 34.79971023480251,32.07083335300256,0 34.79959122858838,32.07086022634235,0 34.79947508289758,32.07091343448649,0 34.79935881388468,32.07096669690968,0 34.79923664471844,32.07096729415576,0 34.79912177286835,32.07104658864036,0 34.79897487097949,32.07112570720702,0 34.79888722467972,32.07117851366566,0 34.79874279960763,32.07128423680869,0 34.79859521904459,32.07136355322666,0 34.79847863488154,32.07144297230025,0 34.79836191935064,32.07152248079761,0 34.79824507343032,32.0716020779166,0 34.79815930685992,32.07168178041764,0 34.79804221359166,32.07176155720244,0 34.79795616172054,32.07184141068195,0 34.79780186844395,32.07186773731328,0 34.79771004064962,32.07189410373302,0 34.79755567970174,32.07192044177337,0 34.79737002328232,32.07194676924303,0 34.79727810620915,32.07197315444336,0 34.79715489998476,32.07199952999493,0 34.79703464286722,32.07205290681115,0 34.79691221087469,32.07207970997565,0 34.79675876113444,32.07213229667552,0 34.79663616578725,32.0721590945553,0 34.7965158855734,32.07221272652451,0 34.79639416450348,32.07224005534155,0 34.79627182383982,32.0722671214403,0 34.79615136355047,32.07232087918774,0 34.79603111665515,32.07237484412778,0 34.79587977302003,32.07242903225671,0 34.79575748160032,32.07245637773539,0 34.79566802521082,32.07251032888696,0 34.79554559731859,32.0725377149133,0 34.7953920225424,32.07256527306239,0 34.79526945233749,32.0725926876614,0 34.79511746292694,32.07264708033384,0 34.79499646538875,32.07270136187387,0 34.79484421345469,32.07275585259577,0 34.79469350541614,32.07283727044721,0 34.79454094840708,32.07289188109038,0 34.79445066170941,32.07294620859783,0 34.79429947907723,32.07302786809845,0 34.79417935372582,32.07310945773398,0 34.79405908038837,32.07319114700508,0 34.79396995394126,32.07327275893679,0 34.79384894225318,32.07335428163514,0 34.79375984266765,32.07343628067046,0 34.79370429835355,32.0735459736907,0 34.7935859422501,32.07368222179287,0 34.79352747616914,32.07376408535365,0 34.79343884580583,32.0738733516459,0 34.79338184365402,32.07398284753502,0 34.79329618372842,32.07414739357892,0 34.79323897373596,32.07425729258198,0 34.79321351678169,32.07436742867609,0 34.79315774177752,32.07450527183566,0 34.7931638907124,32.07461567862387,0 34.79313756341858,32.07472559651252,0 34.79308060933013,32.07488922871619,0 34.79308668160002,32.07502628954131,0 34.79306169465262,32.07519062337077,0 34.79306654712603,32.07530060450269,0 34.7930726226885,32.07543826193546,0 34.79307748970315,32.07554853348597,0 34.79308358050082,32.07568655516418,0 34.79312100317883,32.07579772781796,0 34.79312913357973,32.07596471974184,0 34.79320073097958,32.07610491366522,0 34.79324001895942,32.07624496040656,0 34.79331184498919,32.07638565505223,0 34.79338439099767,32.07652730316914,0 34.79348948121997,32.07666948095191,0 34.79356102661898,32.07678367363563,0 34.79363277125226,32.07689815246911,0 34.79373893916443,32.07704173685054,0 34.7938780624815,32.07718612353797,0 34.79394685121213,32.07724411316636,0 34.7940845259789,32.07736014101853,0 34.7942478923755,32.07736197857023,0 34.79434418144339,32.07733449643025,0 34.79426962949542,32.0771904711012,0 34.79419157753938,32.07698960676555,0 34.79418286657731,32.07684741254325,0 34.79417208286176,32.07665030740839,0 34.79419705423733,32.07651030455318,0 34.7943117016162,32.0763370055064,0 34.79455401995362,32.07613750896425,0 34.79507732694918,32.07582724175629,0 34.79569820277227,32.07560031244044,0 34.79641301741539,32.07540067696312,0 34.79671812423208,32.07525923733243,0 34.79748225018561,32.07497531079491,0 34.79790904184041,32.07478083399741,0 34.79821638657583,32.07467026816978,0 34.79843082137442,32.07458750245045,0 34.79858377461076,32.07453211731625,0 34.79870506867704,32.07447686849413,0 34.79888439004131,32.07436670422536,0 34.79897891672719,32.07436642917416,0 34.80456863371455,32.07677736098206,0 34.80325305348363,32.08274279321805,0 34.80114526065506,32.08251913159533,0 34.7989367189419,32.08176427089727,0 34.79689106024489,32.08073788341836,0 34.79496709037093,32.07958475554416,0 34.79338530277534,32.07829895286428,0 34.7921299991481,32.07665877832899,0 34.79192403865202,32.0763383042137,0 34.79124200995466,32.07505327258005,0 34.79073442377671,32.0738210151859,0 34.79051041161056,32.07323725668621,0 34.79204628706525,32.07302959330549,0 34.79245272972145,32.07270015175266,0 34.79245107794317,32.07265092435394,0 34.79247769467587,32.0710871628869,0 34.79223057128755,32.06931261051965,0 34.79176481038415,32.06790379237363,0 34.79070020423727,32.0662614853681,0 34.78878317579658,32.06475962751786,0 34.78715720473755,32.06306907146922,0 34.78611876597962,32.06156309442464,0 34.78530437871997,32.05935205019298,0 34.78939954851906,32.05930676237435,0 34.78939814232462,32.05666867110639,0 34.80026976529742,32.05646319471511,0 34.80019035465028,32.06112887667786,0 34.79906659112366,32.06429129374197,0 34.79991805485883,32.070779943443,0 
                    </coordinates>
                </LinearRing>
            </outerBoundaryIs>
        </Polygon>
    </Placemark>
</Document>
</kml>
```

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can access the layer placemarks and get it's geometry. If it's a polygon, you can check if the user location lies inside the polygon (taking into account that a polygon may have holes and you need to check if the location lies on a hole which implies that the polygon does not contain the location).

Checking whether the location lies inside any polygon in any container of the file recursively.

```
LatLng latLngTest; // The location to test. You will initialize it with your user's location
List<KmlPolygon> polygonsInLayer = getPolygons(layer.getContainers());
boolean liesInside = liesOnPolygon(polygonsInLayer, latLngTest);

private List<KmlPolygon> getPolygons(Iterable<KmlContainer> containers) {
    List<KmlPolygon> polygons = new ArrayList<>();

    if (containers == null) {
        return polygons;
    }

    for (KmlContainer container : containers) {
        polygons.addAll(getPolygons(container));
    }

    return polygons;
}

private List<KmlPolygon> getPolygons(KmlContainer container) {
    List<KmlPolygon> polygons = new ArrayList<>();

    if (container == null) {
        return polygons;
    }

    Iterable<KmlPlacemark> placemarks = container.getPlacemarks();
    if (placemarks != null) {
        for (KmlPlacemark placemark : placemarks) {
            if (placemark.getGeometry() instanceof KmlPolygon) {
                polygons.add((KmlPolygon) placemark.getGeometry());
            }
        }
    }

    if (container.hasContainers()) {
        polygons.addAll(getPolygons(container.getContainers()));
    }

    return polygons;
}

private boolean liesOnPolygon(List<KmlPolygon> polygons, LatLng test) {
    boolean lies = false;

    if (polygons == null || test == null) {
        return lies;
    }

    for (KmlPolygon polygon : polygons) {
        if (liesOnPolygon(polygon, test)) {
            lies = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    return lies;
}

private boolean liesOnPolygon(KmlPolygon polygon, LatLng test) {
    boolean lies = false;

    if (polygon == null || test == null) {
        return lies;
    }

    // Get the outer boundary and check if the test location lies inside
    ArrayList<LatLng> outerBoundary = polygon.getOuterBoundaryCoordinates();
    lies = PolyUtil.containsLocation(test, outerBoundary, true);

    if (lies) {
        // Get the inner boundaries and check if the test location lies inside
        ArrayList<ArrayList<LatLng>> innerBoundaries = polygon.getInnerBoundaryCoordinates();
        if (innerBoundaries != null) {
            for (ArrayList<LatLng> innerBoundary : innerBoundaries) {
                // If the test location lies in a hole, the polygon doesn't contain the location
                if (PolyUtil.containsLocation(test, innerBoundary, true)) {
                    lies = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return lies;
}
```

Comment: it's not get into the for loop... in debag ti say that the 'layers : kmlLayers@5580 ' what does it meen?
i put your code right after the map put the user location in the 'onLocationChanged'

Comment: Can you inspect the layer object in debut? Does it include any placemark?

Comment: oh.. sorry. i just understand what you meen.
i inspected in debug. i dont find any placemark
but i hope i inspected right... :(

Comment: The problem is that the kml you are importing does not have any readable placemark or it is malformed. Can you try using this example kml? https://www.google.es/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/KML_Samples.kml&ved=0ahUKEwjCubejl7TLAhWEshQKHSziCisQFggiMAE&usg=AFQjCNFXvmR0VXT1YNLH1irpbZAkJE1TYg

Comment: i can't. i must to use my kml :(

Comment: but in the XML i see placemark in my file
look at the end of it

Comment: Yep, of course, but just to try with a kml that is well formed for sure

Comment: mmm..but your kml throw exeptio:
Image at this URL could not be found http://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/images/etna.jpg
and: 
                                                                            java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.lang.String com.google.maps.android.kml.KmlGeometry.getGeometryType()' on a null object reference

i just changed the resurs of the kml

Comment: Got it! I was getting the placemarks of the layer, but I must get the placemarks of a container

Comment: i glad you got it.
but i dont understand :)

Comment: can we speek in skype??

Comment: I'm away from my computer now, but you can take a look at the kml reference https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#description_23

Comment: I have edited my answer. It should work for your kml now

Comment: it is working!!!!
if you have time can you explain to me exactly what you did?
i understant only parts of it.
thank you very much!!!!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105867/discussion-between-antonio-and-roish).